# Does the Higgs field create time?

Tags: particle-physics, inertial-frames, time, standard-model, higgs

In my ongoing series of time questions, here is another.

Particles with mass experience time, example, radioactive particles decay at a predictable rate and in accordance with time dilation.

Massless particles travel at the speed of light at which time is said to be zero.

So if massless particles do not interact with the Higgs field and do not experience time, while mass particles do interact with the Higgs field and do experience time, is time a consequence of interacting with the Higgs field?

Comment: "In my ongoing series of time questions..." You need to stop. This question is mostly just confused gibberish/jargon. Starting from confusion and then adding in QFT jargon will not help the confusion.

Comment: Mass also arises in QCD out of chiral symmetry breaking and can be around without Higgs fields. It is a red herring when it comes to defining time.

Comment: @hft, Asking questions on a question and answer site - the horror! Seriously though, I think there is a logic in my thought process, however wrong it may be. But a simple "no", "I don't know", or even silence would have sufficed. The answer by Miyase taught me something I didn't know which is how we learn so...

Comment: You should have stuck with your original comment. What was it? "Message received"? Apparently, message not received.

Comment: On a serious note, if you are (or think you might be) suffering from manic depression, you should seek treatment from a doctor.

Comment: @hft, I often try to be an instigator of inspiration. When someone is having a problem, I offer to be a sounding board. Sometimes I just listen, other times I ask questions. Those questions can be insightful or irrelevant. But often they inspire the person to see things differently and they come up with a solution. The reverse also happens, people say things that inspire solutions for me. So my goal is first to learn and second to try to inspire. I'm not sure why this particular question deserves your derision but you've reminded me of the old saying, I have learned kindness from the unkind...

Comment: @hft, would it be acceptable to ask, How does time arise in classical mechanics? Or, Where does time come from in QFT? Or should I also expect further disparagement from you for those?

Comment: I want to be clear. I am not attempting to disparage you. Time is a parameter in both classical and quantum mechanics. It is also a parameter in QFT. It does not "arise" from anything. You seem concerned about the concept of "time." This is not unreasonable. But you have to understand that not every noun "X" in a language has a corresponding physical object that can be pointed to and stated "that is X." Time, in this sense, is not a directly demonstrable object; that is, the noun "time" is not directly demonstrable in the same way as, for example, the noun "apple" is.

Comment: @hft, well, thank you. That was a gracious rejoinder. Yes, time is an enduring mystery that consistently gnaws at me until I have to write about it or ask these types of questions. And yes, I have read several articles from people who hypothesize that time is a completely human thing (which I reject since atoms decay and stars die irrespective of humanity), that it is not a thing (like you said) but is an emergent phenomenon of other physical properties such as heat gain or loss. How it slows down at speed or in a gravity well, is absolutely fascinating to me. Why? Why does it do that?

Comment: @hft, so as I have said elsewhere, people on here have my trust that they know what they’re talking about, that they are gracious enough to spend their own time to answer hard, trivial, and sometimes even nonsensical questions for those of us who don’t have years to study this subject. And I hope that someone will eventually figure out what time is and can explain it in a way I can understand.

Comment: @hft, once I even asked if time was THE fundamental force that creates everything. A crazy idea for sure. But since no one seems to be able to say exactly what it is, even though we all experience it everyday, why NOT throw crazy ideas out there and see if someone smarter than me gets inspired? As I said, I am maybe a little obsessed with what time is and how it works.

Comment: @hft, for example, everything happens because of time. Take a simulation, most use time as the fundamental causative action. When time ticks, events happen. When time ticks again, stuff happens again. A field fluctuates, impacts another field at the next tick of time and so on. So to me, and I am almost assuredly wrong, time IS the fundamental driving force for anything happening. Entropy exists, therefore there must be a ticking of time or everything would be static. Time must happen for any change of particles or fields to occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not within the framework of known physics. The Higgs is described in quantum field theory, a theory in which space-time is a "pre-existing" notion, with fields being functions of space and time.

In other words, in quantum field theory, space-time has no dynamics, it's a flat manifold with constant metric.

Comment: So time still exists if all particles are massless and non-interacting?

Comment: @Gerald That’s what is assumed, isn’t it?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes. But doesn't need time real interacting particles to form irreversible thermodynamic processes? Or is the evolving field of these massless particles, say photons, a form of time? The can interact with the virtual particles in the vacuum. Maybe virtual particles constitute a circular time, going back and forth in time simultaneously? Do irreversible unidirectional thermodynamic processes *constitute* time? Or evolve *in* time? We can measure them with a (quasi) periodic process, the clock, of which it in the ideal case can't be seen if it moves forward or backward.

Comment: @CosmasZachos The virtual particle maybe can be seen as a particle constituting an ideal clock (truly periodic process). But again does a process evolve in time or *is* it time. According to relativity it is the perfect clock. Which measures the irreversible thermodynamic processes. Does that clock measure time? Of course. Was the clock before the big bang that virtual particle?

Comment: "Give time time.“

Comment: @miyase, Fascinating - and thanks. I appreciate you taking time out of your day to indulge my curiosity.